# Unable to dowload file using os.system

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

I am trying to download a file using os.system in python and it never completely downloads the file 
Here is the code

```py
 import os
 url = 'wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzQ6rtO2VN95cmNuc2xwUS1wdEE" -O- | sed -rn "s/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p")&id=0BzQ6rtO2VN95cmNuc2xwUS1wdEE" -O cnn_stories_tokenized.zip && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt'
 os.system(url)
```

On trying to download the file with that with the same command on the terminal works just fine, are there any escape characters that I should be handling?

Comment: Yes. There are `\1` and `\n` in the string and Python tries to interpret it like a normal escape sequence. Add `r` just at the opening quote `'` (making it `r'wget...`) to make it a raw string and Python will not try to interpret things that look like escape codes (e.g. `r'\n'` == `'\\n`). Anywhere you have a path to file or regex, just use raw strings to not worry about escaping backslashes by yourself.

Comment: Perfect It works like a charm! thanks. Please add this as an answer and i will accept it and it will here for any ones reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there any escape characters that I should be handling?

Short answer: Yes.

There are \1 and \n in the string and Python tries to interpret it like a normal escape sequence.

You can either escape them manually by doubling each backslash or make it into raw string.

To make a raw string, add `r` just at the opening quote `'` (making it `r'wget...`). "Raw" means Python will use it as-is, and not try to interpret things that look like escape codes (e.g. r'\n' == '\n). Anywhere you have a path to file or regex, just use raw strings to not worry about escaping backslashes by yourself and just paste what you wrote somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

There is one way, you can ran this command. I think you might be already knowing the answer.

Save the linux command as shell script:
e.g.: `vi downloader.sh`

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzQ6rtO2VN95cmNuc2xwUS1wdEE" -O- | sed -rn "s/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p")&id=0BzQ6rtO2VN95cmNuc2xwUS1wdEE" -O cnn_stories_tokenized.zip && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

save the file. call this file from python.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["bash", "downloader.sh"])
```

This is one way which can solve your problem, other alternatives using python libraries is also possible like

> requests package

Comment: Thanks, I have that as a part of the code and i dont think so i can keep adding the `.sh` file each time i run the python script